# Does boosting documents work with wildcard searches?

Tags: lucene, ravendb

Given the following index definition, will the boost be applied when a query such as `Content:(Morel*)` is used?

I've added two documents to the database, one of type `Article` and one of type `Response`. Both with identical `Title`, `Body` and `Tags`. When I run the above query against the index in Raven Studio, both documents come back with the same `$Temp:Score`.

```
AddMap<Article>(docs => from doc in docs
                        select new
                        {
                            Content = new object[]
                            {
                                 doc.Title,
                                 doc.Body,
                                 doc.Tags
                            }
                         }.Boost(5));  // <-- Boost Article documents.

AddMap<Response>(docs => from doc in docs
                         select new
                         {
                             Content = new object[]
                             {
                                  doc.Title,
                                  doc.Body,
                                  doc.Tags
                             }
                          });

Index("Content", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
```

I'm searching using the following code

```
var searchTerms = string.Join(" OR ",  
                              q.Split(new[] { ' ' },   
                                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  
                               .Select(x => string.Format("{0}*",x)));
var query = RavenSession.Advanced
                        .LuceneQuery<IIndexedEntity, AllDocumentByContent>()
                        .Include(x => x.Author)
                        .Search("Content", searchTerms);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be applied when you make the query.